# How would I make a game like diep.io?

Tags: java

I started to learn how to code HTML, but apparently I need to use java for this one. Are there any good tutorials out there?

Comment: You should avoid asking questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" as these are all subjective and does not fit the format of stack exchange. These are better suited for discussion boards.

Answer (score 1):

Any programming language will do. Please note that HTML is NOT a programming language.

If you are looking for a tutorial for any language, the best thing to do is start with a search like : `Java Tutorial` on Google, you will find more thant you need, even posts on SO telling which ones are the best.